# prediction using PCA in R

Tags: r, pca

I'm calculating a PCA using the `prcomp` function in `R` and I have a short question about the prediction capabilities within this object.

I'm using the `iris` data set:

```
# Load data
data(iris)
head(iris, 3)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
```

The code is as follows:

```
data(iris)
# log transform 
log.ir <- log(iris[, 1:4])
ir.species <- iris[, 5]

# apply PCA - scale. = TRUE is highly 
# advisable, but default is FALSE. 
ir.pca <- prcomp(log.ir,center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
```

When one wants to run a prediction based on this PCA, one can easily run:

```
predict(ir.pca, newdata=tail(log.ir, 2))
```

The question is, lets say I have a similar data set as `iris` but **MINUS** one column.

```
tt <- log.ir[,1:3]
head(tt)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
1     1.629241    1.252763    0.3364722
2     1.589235    1.098612    0.3364722
3     1.547563    1.163151    0.2623643
4     1.526056    1.131402    0.4054651
5     1.609438    1.280934    0.3364722
6     1.686399    1.360977    0.5306283
```

Why can't I run the prediction using the set of columns I have? Are there any recommendations on how I should address this problem?

Comment: What you are asking is essentially: Why can't I predict `y` from `X` without knowing `X`, except that in your case you don't observe part of `X`. It seems logical to me that without knowing values for your predictors, you cannot use them to predict something. You either need to reduce `X` to observable parts, or fill in the blanks in `X` for the unobservable parts.

Comment: Well, If you have have 4 indications about a specific thing and you build supposedly a PCA out of these 4 indications, it should be possible to use 3 indications (that are a part of the 4 used to build the "model") and make a prediction based on them .. I don't see what is the problem here. Maybe the the solution is not a PCA, but I asked for other suggestions ..

Comment: Well, if this is really what you want to do, just add a column of zeros with the appropriate name and the predictions will work. Note though that each individual coefficient is derived with all other columns present, so it is unclear if this is really useful.

Comment: if it is not really useful, in what other ways can I address this problem?

Comment: As I said above, fill in the blanks in a meaningful way, or re-estimate the model with observable parts.